# Eclipse Workbench Window with always on top wizard

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an API which opens up a new workbench window with my own editor as default editor.

Now when I call this API in a wizard , which has always-on-top behavior, my new workbench window opens up but when I even click on this window it gets below the already opened wizard. When I close this wizard, the newly workbench window works fine.

So my question is, can I open a new workbench window on top of a wizard using -

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().openWorkbenchWindow(<my_perspective_id>, null);
```

Detailed example, say X is my initial workbench window , I open a wizard W from that workbench window X...........
Now in that wizard I call an API to open up my new workbench window , but this workbench window doesn't stay in focus. Any Solutions ?
Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't get the window above the wizard. The always on top setting for the wizard applies to the entire application.

Comment: Thank You Greg , answers me !